# Reverse Engineering Windows kernel routines

Tags: windows, assembly, x86

## Problem

I'm trying to reverse engineer some Windows kernel routines on a Windows 7 x86 (Home Basic) VM with kd. I have already reversed KeInitializeDpc by disassambling it. The problem with `KeReadyThread` is that I can't tell where the *third* and the *fourth* `mov` are pointing to,as the function doesn't seem to have any argument or anything that can help me.

*This is the code*

```
lkd> uf KeReadyThread  
nt!KeReadyThread:
829080f6 8bff            mov     edi,edi  
829080f8 56              push    esi  
829080f9 8bf0            mov     esi,eax  
829080fb 8b4650          mov     eax,dword ptr [esi+50h]  
829080fe 8b4874          mov     ecx,dword ptr [eax+74h]  
82908101 f6c107          test    cl,7  
82908104 7409            je      nt!KeReadyThread+0x19 (8290810f)  

nt!KeReadyThread+0x10:  
82908106 e8e7cef6ff      call    nt!KiInSwapSingleProcess (82874ff2)  
8290810b 84c0            test    al,al  
8290810d 7505            jne     nt!KeReadyThread+0x1e (82908114)  

nt!KeReadyThread+0x19:  
8290810f e87c70feff      call    nt!KiFastReadyThread (828ef190)  

nt!KeReadyThread+0x1e:  
82908114 5e              pop     esi  
82908115 c3              ret
```

*_KTHREAD structure*

```
lkd> dt _KTHREAD
nt!_KTHREAD
   +0x000 Header           : _DISPATCHER_HEADER
   +0x010 CycleTime        : Uint8B
   +0x018 HighCycleTime    : Uint4B
   +0x020 QuantumTarget    : Uint8B
   +0x028 InitialStack     : Ptr32 Void
   +0x02c StackLimit       : Ptr32 Void
   +0x030 KernelStack      : Ptr32 Void
   +0x034 ThreadLock       : Uint4B
   +0x038 WaitRegister     : _KWAIT_STATUS_REGISTER
   +0x039 Running          : UChar
   +0x03a Alerted          : [2] UChar
   +0x03c KernelStackResident : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x03c ReadyTransition  : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x03c ProcessReadyQueue : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x03c WaitNext         : Pos 3, 1 Bit
   +0x03c SystemAffinityActive : Pos 4, 1 Bit
   +0x03c Alertable        : Pos 5, 1 Bit
   +0x03c GdiFlushActive   : Pos 6, 1 Bit
   +0x03c UserStackWalkActive : Pos 7, 1 Bit
   +0x03c ApcInterruptRequest : Pos 8, 1 Bit
   +0x03c ForceDeferSchedule : Pos 9, 1 Bit
   +0x03c QuantumEndMigrate : Pos 10, 1 Bit
   +0x03c UmsDirectedSwitchEnable : Pos 11, 1 Bit
   +0x03c TimerActive      : Pos 12, 1 Bit
   +0x03c Reserved         : Pos 13, 19 Bits
   +0x03c MiscFlags        : Int4B
   +0x040 ApcState         : _KAPC_STATE
   +0x040 ApcStateFill     : [23] UChar
   +0x057 Priority         : Char
   +0x058 NextProcessor    : Uint4B
   +0x05c DeferredProcessor : Uint4B
   +0x060 ApcQueueLock     : Uint4B
   +0x064 ContextSwitches  : Uint4B
   +0x068 State            : UChar
   +0x069 NpxState         : Char
   +0x06a WaitIrql         : UChar
   +0x06b WaitMode         : Char
   +0x06c WaitStatus       : Int4B
   +0x070 WaitBlockList    : Ptr32 _KWAIT_BLOCK
   +0x074 WaitListEntry    : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x074 SwapListEntry    : _SINGLE_LIST_ENTRY
   +0x07c Queue            : Ptr32 _KQUEUE
   +0x080 WaitTime         : Uint4B
   +0x084 KernelApcDisable : Int2B
   +0x086 SpecialApcDisable : Int2B
   +0x084 CombinedApcDisable : Uint4B
   +0x088 Teb              : Ptr32 Void
   +0x090 Timer            : _KTIMER
   +0x0b8 AutoAlignment    : Pos 0, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 DisableBoost     : Pos 1, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 EtwStackTraceApc1Inserted : Pos 2, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 EtwStackTraceApc2Inserted : Pos 3, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 CalloutActive    : Pos 4, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 ApcQueueable     : Pos 5, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 EnableStackSwap  : Pos 6, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 GuiThread        : Pos 7, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 UmsPerformingSyscall : Pos 8, 1 Bit
   +0x0b8 ReservedFlags    : Pos 9, 23 Bits
   +0x0b8 ThreadFlags      : Int4B
   +0x0bc ServiceTable     : Ptr32 Void
   +0x0c0 WaitBlock        : [4] _KWAIT_BLOCK
   +0x120 QueueListEntry   : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x128 TrapFrame        : Ptr32 _KTRAP_FRAME
   +0x12c FirstArgument    : Ptr32 Void
   +0x130 CallbackStack    : Ptr32 Void
   +0x130 CallbackDepth    : Uint4B
   +0x134 ApcStateIndex    : UChar
   +0x135 BasePriority     : Char
   +0x136 PriorityDecrement : Char
   +0x136 ForegroundBoost  : Pos 0, 4 Bits
   +0x136 UnusualBoost     : Pos 4, 4 Bits
   +0x137 Preempted        : UChar
   +0x138 AdjustReason     : UChar
   +0x139 AdjustIncrement  : Char
   +0x13a PreviousMode     : Char
   +0x13b Saturation       : Char
   +0x13c SystemCallNumber : Uint4B
   +0x140 FreezeCount      : Uint4B
   +0x144 UserAffinity     : _GROUP_AFFINITY
   +0x150 Process          : Ptr32 _KPROCESS
   +0x154 Affinity         : _GROUP_AFFINITY
   +0x160 IdealProcessor   : Uint4B
   +0x164 UserIdealProcessor : Uint4B
   +0x168 ApcStatePointer  : [2] Ptr32 _KAPC_STATE
   +0x170 SavedApcState    : _KAPC_STATE
   +0x170 SavedApcStateFill : [23] UChar
   +0x187 WaitReason       : UChar
   +0x188 SuspendCount     : Char
   +0x189 Spare1           : Char
   +0x18a OtherPlatformFill : UChar
   +0x18c Win32Thread      : Ptr32 Void
   +0x190 StackBase        : Ptr32 Void
   +0x194 SuspendApc       : _KAPC
   +0x194 SuspendApcFill0  : [1] UChar
   +0x195 ResourceIndex    : UChar
   +0x194 SuspendApcFill1  : [3] UChar
   +0x197 QuantumReset     : UChar
   +0x194 SuspendApcFill2  : [4] UChar
   +0x198 KernelTime       : Uint4B
   +0x194 SuspendApcFill3  : [36] UChar
   +0x1b8 WaitPrcb         : Ptr32 _KPRCB
   +0x194 SuspendApcFill4  : [40] UChar
   +0x1bc LegoData         : Ptr32 Void
   +0x194 SuspendApcFill5  : [47] UChar
   +0x1c3 LargeStack       : UChar
   +0x1c4 UserTime         : Uint4B
   +0x1c8 SuspendSemaphore : _KSEMAPHORE
   +0x1c8 SuspendSemaphorefill : [20] UChar
   +0x1dc SListFaultCount  : Uint4B
   +0x1e0 ThreadListEntry  : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x1e8 MutantListHead   : _LIST_ENTRY
   +0x1f0 SListFaultAddress : Ptr32 Void
   +0x1f4 ThreadCounters   : Ptr32 _KTHREAD_COUNTERS
   +0x1f8 XStateSave       : Ptr32 _XSTATE_SAVE
```

## Solution

The only thing that came to my mind as a possible solution is to run the code and see what the registers point to,but on top of not knowing whether it is correct or not, I don't know how to do it. As you may have guessed I'm pretty inexperienced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously, `KeReadyThread` has a single argument passed to it in the `eax` register.

To actually reverse your way to that argument's structure/type you'll need to do quite a bit of reverse engineering.

Luckily for you, the guys at [ReactOS](https://www.reactos.org/) already did that for you.
If you take a look at that link, you'll see ReactOS's implementation of [`KeReadyThread`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/d2/d38/thrdobj_8c.html#ad30c443f4175fcd667aed8d98bc70e5c) accepting a single parameter of the structure [`PKTREAD`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/db/dc9/nt__native_8h.html#a0418f5521057bf02fe3ca9be8ec7a03f).

This is `KeReadyThread`'s code from ReactOS:

```
113 VOID
114 NTAPI
115 KeReadyThread(IN PKTHREAD Thread)
116 {
117     KIRQL OldIrql;
118     ASSERT_THREAD(Thread);
119     ASSERT_IRQL_LESS_OR_EQUAL(DISPATCH_LEVEL);
120 
121     /* Lock the Dispatcher Database */
122     OldIrql = KiAcquireDispatcherLock();
123 
124     /* Make the thread ready */
125     KiReadyThread(Thread);
126 
127     /* Unlock dispatcher database */
128     KiReleaseDispatcherLock(OldIrql);
129 }
```

And specifically, that dereference you're seeing at the top of the assembly you shared is the implementation of [`ASSERT_THREAD`](https://doxygen.reactos.org/dd/d83/ndk_2ketypes_8h.html#aa2ef5c1532eeb201ff804f832967e6f6):

```
#define ASSERT_THREAD (object) ASSERT((((object)->Header.Type & KOBJECT_TYPE_MASK) == ThreadObject))
```

Comment: This sort of confused me even further: why does the command i used { lkd> uf KeInitializeDpc } disassable ASSERT_THREAD ? . I thought I disassembled the function you posted. I'm taking these kernel routines from a book and they are meant to introduce people to re, am I supposed to reverse engineer the arguments too or is it ok to look online ?

Comment: `ASSERT_THREAD` is a macro, not a function. Macros are a C preprocessor constructs. the C preprocessor does (for the sake of this discussion) a simple search&replace before the C compiler starts working on the code. Thus for all intents and purposes, that code *is* part of that function.

Comment: @Nirlzr I understand what a macro is, but this doesn't answer my question: why is the macro even brought in. What I don't understand is, why by trying to disassemble the whole function by using it's **name**, I get a *part* of it that has a different name too. If my logic isn't flawed,in order to have as output `ASSERT_THREAD` I should type  `lkd> uf ASSERT_THREAD` not `KeReadyThread`

Comment: Alright. So there c compiler doesn't see any macros. Macros are translated before the compilation part so there's no `ASSERT_THREAD` object as far as the compiler/debbuger is aware.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that I'm not disassembling KeReadyThread,but what I really can't figure out is: why is it even happening. Why in the snippet I posted, I can only see `ASSERT_THREAD` and not the rest of the code

Comment: I think you do see the rest of `KeReadyThread`'s code. The two calls to `KiInSwapSingleProcess` and `KiFastReadyThread` are from `KeReadyThread`

Answer (score 1):

This Thread Popped up Due To Recent Activity

Quoting from The Accepted Answer An Answer By Nirlzr

> And specifically, that dereference you're seeing at the top of the
>   assembly you shared is the implementation of ASSERT_THREAD:

the Disassembly and Derefernces does not belong to ASSERT_THREAD

the derefernces check the StackCount memeber of _KAPC_STATE.Process.StackCount

```
kd> dt nt!_ETHREAD Tcb.ApcState.Process->StackCount.StackCount
   +0x000 Tcb                                         : 
      +0x040 ApcState                                    : 
         +0x010 Process                                     : 
            +0x074 StackCount                                  : 
               +0x000 StackCount                                  : Pos 3, 29 Bits
```

googling geoffrey chappel _KTHREAD will provide more information about the overlay and  the Priortity member a char which is fitted inside KAPC_STATE for x86

Answer (score 0):

The third move is referring to a member inside the Thread argument (shown in the ReactOS source linked by Nirlzr) which is at offset +0x50. As seen in the _KTHREAD struct there's nothing at offset +0x50 and the 2 closest members we have at that offset are ApcState and ApcStateFill. Looking further into ApcStateFill is pointless as it is just a string and would render the fourth move pointless, however ApcState is interesting as it is a _KAPC_STATE struct. Interestingly enough, ApcState has a member at +0x10 which is called Process which works accordingly with the third move where we move a member value at offset +[0x40 + 0x10]. The fourth move refers to a pointer to another struct of _KPROCESS at the Process member earlier discussed in the _KAPC_STATE struct. This pointer to a _KPROCESS + 0x70 gives us the member StackCount. And in the end, cl ends up with the value at the member StackCount which will be compared with 7.